# Automapper - Mapping is not working for record type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to map a class to a record and it seems to blow up everytime.

The class I have is

```cs
public class CreateStockRequestDto 
{
    public CreateStockRequestDto(string name, string locationId, int quantity)
    {
        Name = name;
        LocationId = locationId;
        Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public string Name { get; init; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public string? Sku { get; set; }

    public string LocationId { get; init; }
}
```

I want it to map to a record

```cs
public record Stock
{
    public Stock(StockId stockId, string itemName, int quantity, string? sku = null)
    {
        if (!Guid.TryParse(stockId.Id, out _))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid stock id {stockId.Id}", nameof(stockId));
        }

        if (quantity <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid quantity : {quantity}", nameof(quantity));
        }

        if (!IsValidItemName(itemName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid item name {itemName}", nameof(itemName));
        }

        StockId = stockId;
        ItemName = itemName;
        Quantity = quantity;
        Sku = sku;
    }

    public StockId StockId { get; init; }
    public string ItemName { get; init; }
    public int Quantity { get; init; }
    public string? Sku { get; init; }

    private static bool IsValidItemName(string itemName)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(itemName, RegularExpressions.ItemNameRegex);
    }
}
```

I am using Automapper for mapping functionality, but I keep getting an error which states

> Location.Domain.ValueObjects.Stock needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args. Validate your configuration for details. (Parameter 'type')

```cs
public class StockProfile : Profile
{
    public StockProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Stock, CreateStockResponseDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, input => input.MapFrom(src => src.StockId.Id))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, input => input.MapFrom(src => src.ItemName));

        CreateMap<CreateStockRequestDto, Stock>()
            .ForPath(x => x.StockId, opt => opt.MapFrom(o => new StockId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Quantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(o => o.Quantity))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemName, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: which part of the error message isnt clear?

Comment: had used the .ForCtorParam but I had mixed it up with 

`.ForMember CreateMap<CreateStockRequestDto, Stock>()             .ForCtorParam("stockId", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new StockId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())))             .ForMember(dest => dest.Quantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(o => o.Quantity))             .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemName, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Name)); `

and it kept throwing me error AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: Stock does not have a constructor with a parameter named 'stockId'. which was misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario, you need [Constructor mapping](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Construction.html) by providing the constructor parameters via `.ForCtorParam()`.

```cs
public class StockProfile : Profile
{
    public StockProfile()
    {
        ...

        CreateMap<CreateStockRequestDto, Stock>()
            .ForCtorParam("quantity", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quantity))
            .ForCtorParam("stockId", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new StockId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())))
            .ForCtorParam("itemName", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
    }
}
```

[Sample NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4DUqFG)

Comment: AM is case insensitive so `quantity` matches by default.

Comment: I had used the .ForCtorParam but I had mixed it up with .ForMember

`CreateMap<CreateStockRequestDto, Stock>()
            .ForCtorParam("stockId", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new StockId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Quantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(o => o.Quantity))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemName, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Name));`

and it kept throwing me error 

AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: Stock does not have a constructor with a parameter named 'stockId'.

which was misleading

Comment: I guess auto mapper doesn't like using both ForCtorParam and ForMember in single go.

Comment: I think you need `.CtorParam()` for `ItemName`. [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rPEZfJ)

Comment: Unless you need to modify the `itemName` parameter name in the constructor as `name`. That matches @Lucian's suggestion. [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LoJh1g)